# Installing multiple version of NodeJS

Tags: apache, node.js, forever

I need to know how I can install NodeJS multiple times on the same machine. I know about NVM but that only allows me to have 1 active version of node at once. I need to have these running concurrently.

[Forever](https://npmjs.org/package/forever) also need to be installed on each of these node installs.

I have no idea what I'm doing at all here. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's not OK to have one VM for each node version you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create multiple symbolic links to the install locations of your node versions:

e.g. install V1 like this:

```
cd /opt
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.17/node-v0.8.17.tar.gz
tar zxf node-v0.8.17.tar.gz
cd node-v0.8.17
./configure --prefix=/opt/node-v0.8.17 && make install
```

then create the sym-link:
e.g.:

```
cd /opt
ln -s node-v0.8.17 nodeV1
```

run this node installation with:

```
nodeV1
```

(repeat with different locations & sym-links for your other versions)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can try to use option "--prefix" when you will be install node js

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/node_version
```